# Ubuntu 14.04 logs me out when I try to lock screen

Tags: login, lock

I'm having a weird problem where every time I try to lock the screen, Ubuntu logs me out instead. And when I log back in after locking, it makes me login twice: First I enter my password with the generic login background, then the screen goes black and the background changes to my desktop, then I have to enter my password again, then it goes to my desktop.

Comment: ..but you are not **really logged-out**, right? I had the same issue, then once I upgraded to 15.04 it is working correctly.

Comment: Yep, I'm actually logged out--once I log back in, everything is gone.

Comment: Try upgrading to 15.04